# Prepared select statement not working to get count

Tags: php, mysql, select, prepared-statement

This SELECT prepared statement is supposed to echo the amount of categories that have 1 which is active. I have the select statement grab everything from the table. How do I make it display the amount of subcategories?

I have already tried using different types of SELECT prepared statements for this code. Messed around with the variables. Checked the config file to make sure the connection is right.

```
<?php
$stmt = $con -> prepare('select * from tblcategory where Is_Active=?');

$Is_Active = 1;

$stmt -> bind_param('i', $Is_Active);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> store_result();
$stmt -> bind_result($Is_Active);
$stmt -> fetch();
echo $Is_Active;
?>
```

I expect the code to give me the amount of categories that are active from each table.

Comment: Why do you expect this to give a count? You would get that with `SELECT COUNT(*)`

Comment: `SELECT *` returns all the columns in the table, not a count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the count you need to select `COUNT(*)`, not just `*`.

```
$stmt = $con -> prepare('select COUNT(*) from tblcategory where Is_Active=?');
```